# Plotting the inverse of the numbers in columns in gnuplot with for loop

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot

I want to plot the inverse of the numbers in a number of columns against the first column:

```
plot for [i=1:30] 'file' using 1:(1/i) w lp
```

which results in all the y values to be zero. It works when I remove the for loop and just pick a column to plot: `p 'file' u 1:(1/$4)`. What am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the parentheses the `i` is only an integer number,  and you get always zero. To access the value of a column inside an expression, use `column(i)`:

```
plot for [i=1:30] 'file' using 1:(1/column(i)) w lp
```

The `$4` is a shortcut for `column(4)`. To understand this better, have a look at

```
i = 2
plot 'file' u 1:i, '' u 1:(i)
```